# Switching keyboard configurations depending on keyboard in use

Tags: macos, mac

I have this keyboard: http://www.staples.com/Microsoft-Natural-Ergonomic-Keyboard-4000/product_617433?cid=PS:GooglePLAs:617433&srccode=cii_17588969&cpncode=35-151752079-2 and am now using it on a mac.  The key configurations are driving me nuts.  I understand I can remap keys in the Preferences & Settings, but I want to maintain normal keyboard configuration when my Microsoft keyboard is not plugged in.

Is it possible to switch keyboard configurations depending on which keyboard is in use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The settings in System Preferences should already be keyboard-specific. If you have two or more keyboards connected, there should be a menu for selecting the keyboard at the top:

[image]

You could also try to use a private.xml like this with KeyRemap4MacBook:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <devicevendordef>
    <vendorname>KINESIS</vendorname>
    <vendorid>0x05f3</vendorid>
  </devicevendordef>
  <deviceproductdef>
    <productname>ADVANTAGE</productname>
    <productid>0x0007</productid>
  </deviceproductdef>
  <item>
    <name>test</name>
    <identifier>test</identifier>
    <device_only>DeviceVendor::KINESIS, DeviceProduct::ADVANTAGE</device_only>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::CONTROL_L, KeyCode::OPTION_L</autogen>
  </item>
</root>
```

See http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en or http://osxnotes.net/keyremap4macbook.html for more information.